# wp_nav_menu doesn't generate parent/ancestor classes

Tags: menus, customization, navigation

I don't know why the proper classes for menu item are not generated - all the elements in the tree which has subtree get only `menu-item menu-item-type-post_type`. The elements, which don't have children, get proper classes after being clicked (active).

Link: http://lichens.ie/

Part of the menu structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/thAdm.png

Code

```
$args = array(
    'menu'      => 'Main menu',
    'container' => '',
    'menu_id'   => 'nav',
);
wp_nav_menu($args);
```

When you visit e.g. http://lichens.ie/view-lichens-by/lichens-by-habitat/ you can see that it has no 'current' class. As well as it's parent.

PS Sorry for posting 'not working links' - it's because of reputation limitation

Any ideas - help much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is part of code in `_wp_menu_item_classes_by_context()` that handles current class for pages:

```
// if the menu item corresponds to the currently-queried post or taxonomy object
} elseif (
    $menu_item->object_id == $queried_object_id &&
    (
        ( ! empty( $home_page_id ) && 'post_type' == $menu_item->type && $wp_query->is_home && $home_page_id == $menu_item->object_id ) ||
        ( 'post_type' == $menu_item->type && $wp_query->is_singular ) ||
        ( 'taxonomy' == $menu_item->type && ( $wp_query->is_category || $wp_query->is_tag || $wp_query->is_tax ) )
    )
) {
    $classes[] = 'current-menu-item';
```

1. IDs must match.
2. It must be of `post_type` type.
3. Query should be for `is_singular`.

Second point can be excluded, because CSS class for item type is generated correctly. So something goes wrong either with IDs or `is_singular` conditional.

Are you running any secondary loops on page? Most common reason for conditionals to break is improper use of `query_posts()`.

Comment: You were right! Amazing! That's not a theme that I've prepared (I'm just doing some modifications, adding menu support) and it was the fault of additional query_posts, which was used before calling menu. Many thanks! I feel bad that I cannot vote your answer up yet

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why its not working in your case... Like you say, the active page should be getting 'current_menu_item' added to its classes. If you're having trouble for one reason of another, you can always use the 'nav_menu_css_class' filter to add your own classes. This little bit of code will essentially duplicate the 'current_menu_item' & 'current_menu_parent' classes, and add a 'has_children' class (useful for expandable or dropdown menus):

```
function check_for_submenu($classes, $item) {
    global $wpdb, $post;
    if ($item->ID == $post->ID) array_push($classes,'current_menu_item');
    $has_children = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(meta_id) FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='_menu_item_menu_item_parent' AND meta_value='".$item->ID."'");
    if ($has_children > 0) {
        array_push($classes,'has_children');
        $child_pages = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT c.meta_value FROM wp_postmeta AS c, wp_postmeta AS th 
                                      WHERE c.meta_key = '_menu_item_object_id' AND c.post_id = th.metavalue 
                                      AND th.meta_key= '_menu_item_menu_item_parent' AND th.post_id = {$item->ID}");
        if (in_array($post->ID,$child_pages)) array_push($classes,'current_menu_parent');
    }
    return $classes;
}

add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'check_for_submenu', 10, 2);
```

Of course you want to figure out why the built-in functionality isn't working for you before hacking up something to duplicate it, but you can do a lot with that filter if necessary...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - luckily the answer from Rarst solved the problem (improper use of additional loop before calling menu). I'll save the snippet for future and vote you answer up when I have enough reputation. Greets.